# Plotting seperate graphs over each other pandas

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have 3 separate plots. I want to put them over each other.
What is the simplest means of doing this? 
(The actual graphs have way too much code for me to post here aha.)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Yes, it can be overwhelming to post the whole code. We recommend you to post what you tried as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Create a simple example and post here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. The easiest way is to simply plot each graph separately:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x1 = range(10)
x2= range(10,20)
x3= range(-10,0)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x1)
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x2)
fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x3)
```

To build subplots you can use [subplot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot.html):

```
cols = 1
rows = 3

plt.subplot(rows, cols, 1)
plt.plot(x1)
plt.subplot(rows, cols, 2)
plt.plot(x2)
plt.subplot(rows, cols, 3)
plt.plot(x3)
```

If you need to share an axis, use [subplots](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html):

```
fig, (ax1,ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(nrows=3, sharex=True)
# remove vertical gap between subplots
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=.0)

ax1.grid()
ax2.grid()
ax3.grid()

ax1.plot(x1)
ax2.plot(x2)
ax3.plot(x3)
```

[image]